# How to unify the Google Analytics Session with the application Session?

Tags: session, google-analytics, analytics

By default, the google analytics session ends after every 30 minutes or any given time frame.In our application, the session ends only after 1 hr of inactivity or logout from the application. Since the concept of GA session and the application session are different, the GA reports related to sessions are a bit misleading. The following are some of the few misleading scenarios.

1. A Person logged in and log out 3 times within 30 minutes, the GA shows
   1 session but the application has made 3 sessions.
2. The same user logged in using two different accounts within 30 minutes, in GA the Users value is still 1, but the 'emails login' custom report value is 2.
3. A person stayed on the web for 2 hours and for GA it's 4 sessions
       but 1 session really happened.

The best way to solve this is to unify the application session and the GA session. How do we do that?

All your valuable suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to match sessions exactly, since GA sessions are affected by factors that are not relevant to your application session (GA sessions also end after 500 hits, at midnight or when the traffic channel changes).

Two things you can do:

- The session timeout in GA is configurable with a maximum value of 4 hours, so you can start by changing that (btw. per documentation sessions do not end after 30 minutes, but [after 30 minutes of inactivity](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795871?hl=en))
- since your app seems to require login you can programmatically restart/end the GA session at login/logout via the [session control parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#sessionControl) (at least you can do this with analytics.js, for lack of documentation it's hard to tell if gtag.js supports this)

This should at least bring you closer to synched sessions. You could also create a custom dimension with an identifier for the application session and try to aggregate by that, but that would require some post processing of the data (as GA would not use that parameter to aggregate into sessions).